# Dropbear client configuration file?

Tags: linux, ssh, angstrom-linux

Does anybody know where the Dropbear SSH client looks for a config file? I need to specify a certain identity file to be used by default. Eg, can I setup dropbear client such that I can use

```
$ dbclient user@host
```

instead of

```
$ dbclient -i my/rsa/key user@host
```

?

PS: I'm pretty much stuck with Dropbear rather than OpenSSH since I am on embedded linux running Angstrom.

EDIT: Alternatively, where does the dropbear client look for an identity file by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New dropbear (v2017 ..) has a default id `.ssh/id_dropbear` see help:
`-i <identityfile>`   (multiple allowed, default `.ssh/id_dropbear`)

Comment: It's been a long time since I've needed dropbear myself, but since this question continues to be popular, I'm updating the accepted answer. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 4):

you could create a shell alias... I added this line to my profile

```sh
alias ssh='ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

Comment: In my case the key was under /etc/dropbear, so this worked for ssh/scp: 
`alias ssh='ssh -i /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key'`
`alias scp='scp -i /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key'`

Comment: I think the author was looking for a solution using dropbears dbclient, not openssh client?